# Is there a way to prevent a Windows application from running under Citrix?

Tags: citrix

If I have two versions of a Windows application, one version having additional security features, and I want my customer to use the more secure version if they're going to deploy it to a cloud-based Citrix server, is there a way to have the less secure version refuse to run under Citrix? Can it detect Citrix?

Comment: See https://techsupt.winbatch.com/webcgi/webbatch.exe?techsupt/nftechsupt.web+WIL~Extenders/Terminal~Server+Identify~Citrix~Server.txt